# How to custom Azure AD B2C UserFlow as per need of customer?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are facing an issue while implementation Authentication using Azure AD B2C Instance.

Our Requirement:

**SignUp:**

For the Signup process, we have to call external API to check some status in that API, if iAPI returns true then create a user in Azure AD B2C, or else return with some error on it.

Assume if a user is created successfully in Azure AD B2C (with in the same Userflow), and now we want to store some custom fields that we have configured in Azure AD B2C, those custom fields need to be also stored in our own database, and not in default database provided for Azure AD B2C.

**SignIn:**

For Sign in process, we have to call external API to check some status in that API, if API returns true then continue with the Authentication flow or else return it with some error details.

Please help me with this.

Solution Approach:

Approach 1:  User inbuild provided UserFlow in Azure AD B2C (SignUpSignIn, SignUp, SignIn,               PasswordReset, Profile)

Problem Facing for Approach 1:

During the authentication process, we want to include our own customized page for MFA after the signup or sign-in page.

We are not able to call external API after the user successfully created or login with the existing Userflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty "easily" achievable using the Custom (Trust Framework) Policies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-trust-frameworks

There's also a nice example of using a REST API within

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/rest-api-idp

Note: The example here is using the REST call for authentication purposes, but should outline how you use a REST `Technical Profile` to achieve the flow you are looking for.